# atof only returns integers?

Tags: c++, qt, atof

I've got a routine which gets numbers in the exponent format(e.g. 2,5E-02 or 4E+06) as a QString. When I print the values I always only get integers and when they are smaller then 1 I always get 0.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?
(with the cout line I only wanted to test whether the QString::number() is ruining it for me)

here is a code snippet:

```
QStringList valPair;
value = atof(valPair[0].replace(",",".").toAscii());
value1 =atof(valPair[1].replace(",",".").toAscii());
strValue = "[" + QString::number(value) + ", " + QString::number(value1) + "]";
//cout<<value<<" "<<value1;
```

I'd appreciate any help!

EDIT: It was a Problem with variable declaration...

```
double value, value1;
```

Comment: How is `value` and `value1` declared?

Comment: When you get `2,5E-02` do you print `2` or `0`?  If you print `2` then make sure you locale is `C` (`.` is probably not the decimal point in your locale.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333451/c-locale-independent-atof

Comment: @AndreyT now I feel stupid. I declared the  values as double and it works. Sorry to bother you all!

Comment: If you set the locale correctly. Put `std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));` as the first line in main. Then `operator>>` will decode comma separated numbers (if that is what you expect in your locale as set in your computers settings),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing all that work? Qt already has what you're looking for if you use [QString::toDouble](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toDouble) and [QString::number()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#number-2). If you set your locale manually before calling toDouble() then you can use the comma decimal notation without replacing anything.

You could also create a string template like `QString("[%1,%2]")` and then use the `double` version of `QString::arg`.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion function doesn't support your *locale*, which uses comma as a decimal separator. Use `2.4e4` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! But like I wrote in the comment it was just me being stupid. I had to declare the value/value1 variable as double. The problem with the decimal-character I solved with the replace-function.